# How do I change the CSS for my Shopify shopping cart's product quantities?

Tags: css, shopify

I've noticed that when I view my shopping cart on a mobile phone, I can't see the quantities of what I ordered as long as the product names are long enough - what comes up are product names and prices. I have to scroll to see the quantity. How do I override the default CSS so that I can change how this particular element of the shopping cart page appears on mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your css was first design for desktop and you want to change how it looks in mobile.
You can use css media query for that there are many online resources for it.

Comment: My CSS was designed for both desktop and mobile.